# How to select one cell through the selected id. SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table in which there are 2 columns. The first is the ID, the second is the price. When the user selects a product on the site, a product card is opened (this will be id). At the bottom there is a calculator with prices where you need to load the price from the second column. Question: how to make a request for a specific ID(for loading price from second column). Here's the code that I could do.This code displays all IDs and prices, but need only when you select the product and only for it. Any help. Thank you

```html
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting('E_ALL');//error's show

 $host = 'localhost'; // host name
 $database = 'test_sql'; // database name
 $user = 'root'; // user name
 $pswd = ''; //  password
  
 $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Could not to connect MySQL.");//connect to mySQL
 mysql_select_db($database) or die("Could not to connect database.");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `oc_product`";//load from product table
 $res = mysql_query($query);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);//array call

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
 echo "ID: ".$row['product_id']."<br>";//output for each ID
 echo "Цена: ".$row['price']."<br>";//output for each price
 }
?>
```

Comment: for id = 1  you can  use SELECT price  FROM oc_product where id = 1

Comment: So from my understanding you want to load the price into the calculator ( which is javascript/ or) , and you want that to calculate exactly the total price based on the selected items ? Well you can do it from front-end , when you click to add something to the cart to add the price to the current calculator total. Maybe i didn't understood right ?

Comment: btw... since you are a newbie and still learning. Why don't you start with PDO and prepared statements? MYSQL API is currently no more usable in PHP from version 7

Comment: MikeX, yes calculate use JS. Maybe you are right and understand, probably I can't to express a thought clearly. The idea is that when you click on a product, a SQL request is sent and selects the "price" cell, writes the value to a variable, and the variable is inserted into the calculator

Comment: Lelio Faieta, excuse me, I'm a really new in PHP( and a programming generally ). What is this PDO? It's other method to processing databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you select a product pass that id to the function and update your query like :

```
$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Could not to connect MySQL.");//connect to mySQL
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Could not to connect database.");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `oc_product` WHERE 'product_id' = <id that you passed>";//load from product table
$res = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Comment: how to add id if I don't know what the product will be selected? Am I should add a request for each ID?

Comment: while selecting the product pass that id in url and you can get that value using $_GET

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
echo $id = $_GET['id']; //show 2
}"something like that?"

Comment: so you are passing id in url? then use that $id in query like WHERE 'product_id' = $id;

Comment: I mean the output from the GET will be this way?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try via that)